# JavaScript Image Class - Merge two images next to each other

Tags: javascript, image, merge

is there a way to combine two images in one image class? I don't want to blend them, just put them next to each other...

I'm looking for something like this:

```
myImg = new Image()
myImg.src = "img1.jpg" + "img2.jpg"
```

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I need to combine them before putting them into the canvas for easier scroll-handling... so canvas or div is not an option.

**Edit, II.:**

I'm using a canvas through which I'm scrolling. But my image is chucked. It thought it would be the easiest way, when I merge my actual image with the following and "scroll" through this one instead of handling two seperate ones.

Comment: What's the relation between "easier scroll-handling" and "canvas or div is not an option" ? You can predefine the size, and you won't have a delay between the fetching of the images and their display together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. An image element only support a single image. Either you would have to create two separate images and float them next to each other, or you could use a `canvas` element, and draw both images onto it side by side (if you don't have a very rare scenario at hand, the best solution is likely to use two separate images though).

Comment: I need to combine them before putting them into the canvas for easier scroll-handling... so `canvas` or `div` is not an option.

Comment: @Ron Could you please elaborate a bit more on why scrolling doesn't work with canvas, not sure I'm following you. The way I see it, the canvas would act as if the images were merged.

Comment: @Ron explain "easier scroll-handling". Why would scrolling be different in a DIV versus IMG?

Comment: I can't use either a div nor a canvas... at least this was my idea. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t combine images like that using javascript, unless you use canvas or equivalent techniques.

If you just want to place them next to each other, create a container and append the images:

```
var container = document.createElement('div'),
    createImage = function(src) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = src;
    };
 container.appendChild( createImage('img1.jpg') );
 container.appendChild( createImage('img2.jpg') );
```

Comment: At best I'd like to merge them before putting them into the `Image()`... Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use canvas for that. And in order to load an image into a canvas element, you need to create `Image()` elements anyway (unless you have the raw bitmap data).

Comment: I've updated my question. But if there is no way, then I'll need to handle both images. Its possible but not that easy :)

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery

```
$('.container').append('<img algin="left" src="img1.jpg" />');
$('.container').append('<img algin="left" src="img2.jpg" />');
```